# Any Asynchronous Training Methods for GAN?

Tags: generative-adversarial-network

GAN sometimes get really unstable with the high dimensional data. Can we train GAN is Asynchronous manner? It's like we have one master Generator and Discriminator. But we actually update it asynchronously with gradients from a number of slaves generators and discriminators.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of using asynchronous methods for GAN training similar to how asynchronous updates used in A3C?

I guess the motivation for asynchronous methods in RL is quite different from what you want to solve with async methods in GANs.

RL can be unstable (without async methods) because of the non-stationary nature of the data (i.e. high correlation between consecutive updates). And solving this using async methods kind of makes sense.

GANs are unstable because of the optimization approach (e.g. mini-max) the take in solving the objective function. And more recent GAN variants (e.g. progressive GANs) are significant improvements of the original GAN. Personally, I believe "mode collapse" to be a more pressing matter than the stability.

So not sure if async methods is the answer you're looking for solving stability issues in GANs. Maybe better optimization methods (e.g. penalizing in stabilities in the optimization procedure) might be a better way of going about this?

References
[On Convergence and Stability of GANs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07215.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the valid answer. Well in my network the generator is a model-free RL agent. So somehow I made it stable by using A3C method with PPO. Now I need to inject some kind of imitation learning flavor to the model. So I used Generative Adversarial Imitation learning and followed this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01945.pdf(Connection between GAN and actor-critic).

Comment: I want to make sure my generator takes the GAN output as a part of it's reward signal. Then I can make use of expert's data. Since my generator is Async manner I though the discriminator also should be async. But I cannot find any previous work.

Comment: Oh okey, I wasn't aware of the context in which you're using GANs. Now it makes more sense why you're asking this question. Maybe have that part about what you're trying to solve in the Question?

But, can you use the same muti-gpu deep network approach? Averaging the updates of the several different discriminators and updating a single master with the average?

Comment: It's sort of a back and forth process, async agents do their own thing, send the updates to a master, get the updated version of master, send back to async agents. Do this process every 100 iterations or something like that.

Comment: Do u think averaging a discriminator asynchronously is not desirable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by averaging "asynchronously"? This averaging scheme is something I got from how multi-gpu based networks are implemented. They do individual updates on several copies of the network on each GPU and average the gradients to update a single master copy.

So why I suggested averaging the updates is that it's simple and can test without large amount of coding (or coming up with a really novel way). And if the averaging actually works, it becomes a good benchmark to test any new improvement you propose later.

Comment: yeah, you are talking about data parallelism.   When you have two GPUs you build two towers and update the network as an average. But for methods like A3C, we cannot use that because A3C should have the method of Model Parallelism.  In TF model parallelism is not really clear and sometimes break the process. So I am thinking of updating the discriminator asynchronously as we update the policy net in A3C.